# stopService() não para o serviço

Tags: java, android, android-service

Estou estudando Services no Android, consigo executar o mesmo em um teste simples apenas para entendimento, porém não consigo pará-lo na main activity de jeito nenhum. Acredito que já tentei de tudo. Já tentei colocar o stopSelf() no onDestroy, mudei de todo jeito a chamada do stopService() na main acitivity, mas não dá em nada, o serviço continua rodando. Mostra no onDestroy() que foi destruído, mas continua funcionando. Gostaria de entender melhor essa situação.

Outro questionamento seria em base de... Será que eu consigo parar o serviço, mas como ele está vinculado a uma thread a parte da main, só irá parar realmente quando o que estiver dentro da thread finalizar?

***Setando o campo.***

```
private Intent serviceIntent;
```

***Realizando o startService() e o stopService() no clique dos seus respectivos botões.***

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
ou
stopService(serviceIntent);
```

***Classe extende de IntentService. Única coisa que faz é um contador de 0 à 20 no Log.***

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    // Recebendo o valor passado pela intent.
    int numero = intent.getIntExtra("numero", 50);

    for(int i = 1; i < numero; i++) {
        Log.d("onHandleIntent", ""+i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Isso me parece estranho. Eu fiz um pequeno exemplo que funciona bem pra mim, vc pode fazer algumas modificações e ver o que acontece: https://github.com/calheiros/my-app.git

Comment: Pior que tá praticamente a mesma coisa que você fez, a diferença é que eu coloco um for contando até determinado valor estabelecido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Será que eu consigo parar o serviço, mas como ele está vinculado a uma thread a parte da main, só irá parar realmente quando o que estiver dentro da thread finalizar?

Sim, é exactamente isso que acontece.
Uma coisa é o serviço estar disponível/em funcionamento outra é estar a executar uma tarefa(o código em `onStartCommand()`).
Ou seja, um coisa é o código que mantém o serviço activo outra coisa é a tarefa que ele executa.

O método `startService()` tem duas funções:

- criar o serviço
- chamar o método `onStartCommand()`.

Na primeira chamada o serviço é criado, sendo os seus métodos `onCreate()` e `onStartCommand()` chamados.
A partir desse momento o serviço está disponível e em futuras chamadas a `startService()` apenas é chamado o método `onStartCommand()`.

Talvez seja esta dupla função que cria a confusão.
Seria porventura melhor ter dois métodos, um para criar o serviço: `startService()` e outro para executar o comando: `startCommand()`.

Um Serviço é um componente da aplicação(tal como é uma Activity), a sua criação envolve a alocação de recursos.
O propósito dos métodos
 `stopService()` e `stopSelf()` é indicar, quando o serviço não é mais necessário, que esses recursos podem ser libertados.
Caso a tarefa ainda esteja em execução ela continuará até terminar, seja no método `onStartCommand()` ou em qualquer outra *thread* criada pelo serviço.

Um IntentService não foi desenhado para ser parado externamente. Ele não está preparado para lidar com um `stopService()`.
A sua intenção é executar uma tarefa e, quando terminada, auto parar-se, usando `stopSelf()`.

A tarefa, código no método `onHandleIntent()`, corre numa outra *Thread* que, não sendo parada pela implementação do IntentService em resposta a um `stopService()`, só terminará após a execução de todo o código.
Isso pode ser verificado na [implementação do IntentService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) onde `stopSelf()` é chamado após `onHandleIntent()`.

Terá de usar um mecanismo que pare a *thread* quando o método `onDestroy()` for chamado.
Uma possibilidade, entre [outras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258083/how-to-force-an-intentservice-to-stop-immediately-with-a-cancel-button-from-an-a), é "setar" uma *flag*, testá-la dentro do método `onHandleIntent()` e fazê-lo retornar de imediato.

Note que quem decide quando o método `onDestroy()` é chamado é o Android, o que pode não ser de imediato em relação à chamada de `stopService()`.

Comment: Então só pra confirmar o meu entendimento em relação ao que você falou. No caso um serviço, independendo de ser da super class Service ou com a sub classe IntentService só pode ser parado mediante a finalização do serviço, é isso mesmo? O Service precisa setar o stopSelf() ao final do serviço e a IntentService faz esse procidimento automático, correto?
Mas em relação ao stopService() que pode ser chamado onde foi feito a instância do serviço, qual a real funcionalidade dele? Já que pelo que percebi ele para o serviço mas à atividade gerada na thread continua, isso que não entendi.

Comment: Reformulei a resposta. Espero que tenha ficado mais claro.